# how to find title in highcarts

Tags: javascript, printing, highcharts, menu

I want to add new item to printing menu. You can see my work bottom. Please, help me about this topic.

```
var url = chart.title.textStr.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(750/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(600/2);
    return window.open('itemExport.jsp?Id='+url, 'Export', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+900+', height='+600+', top='+top+', left='+left);
```

Comment: do you want to put chart title in item in printing menu

Comment: yes exactly, i want to do this
'
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.downloadItem = function () {
   
  var url = Highcharts.Chart.setTitle;
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(750/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(600/2);
  return window.open('itemExport.jsp?Id='+url, 'Export', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+900+', height='+600+', top='+top+', left='+left);
 
    };'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get chart title by using `chart.options.title.text`

and this title add to exporting menu as

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkvqvxxy/) demo

```
    Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
      text: chart.options.title.text,
      onclick: function() {
        alert('OK');
       /*call custom function here*/
      }
   });
```

Comment: Check fiddle demo first

Comment: I tried this solution and my project worked correctly, thank you so much.